# Hide / Change / Add an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, src

What I am ultimately trying to do is have a box and an image hidden initially then depending on the result of other functions then un-hide the box (by giving it a background color) and image as well as change the image depending on the function that is called.

I have two problems with the code below:

- First being that upon execution the box appears but the images do
  not.
- Second when either function is called a second time (it throws no
  errors on first call) by the rest of the script (it's a calculator so
  it will happen multiple times) then I get an error as if the image no
  longer exists:

> "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'src' of undefined
>   or null reference"

JScript:

```
function one(input) {
    document.getElementById("result").style.background = "lightgray";
    document.getElementById("result").style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById("icon").src = "tick.png";
    document.getElementById("icon").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function two(input) {
    document.getElementById("result").style.background = "lightgray";
    document.getElementById("result").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("icon").src = 'cross.png';
    document.getElementById("icon").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="result">
<img src="tick.png" id="icon" style="visibility:hidden">
</div>
```

And CSS (doubt that is needed though):

```
#result {


width: 820px;
height: 450px;
border-radius: 20px;
padding-top:25px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
color: green;
font-size:40pt;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-right: 150px;
margin-left:420px;
}

#result img{

margin-top: 85px;
width:220px;
height: 190px;
    }
```

Comment: When you get that error, can you still see the `icon` element in the DOM inspector?

Comment: jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/h5XF2/

Comment: I am unable to replicate your error. Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jDVjP/1/

Comment: Oomlaut, your fiddle does as the OP describes for me in Firefox. I did see the image flash briefly, then it was gone. Subsequent clicks didn't show the image.

Correction: I didn't realize that the final image was all black. I'm not sure why there's a different image source on a hidden element to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar got me thinking, so thank you!

After taking a looking at the DOM while calling the functions turns out another part of the script using .innerText was replacing the  code in the HTML (still don't understand why it would do that) so on first call my  tag was gone hence trying to call a null reference. Putting the  in its own div fixed that problem.

Also added a position attribute set to absolute for the  in the css and that fixed that problem by bring the image back up into view.

Thanks for the help guys, much appreciated! :)